# ArrayAdapter<Item>を継承したクラスでopenFileInputで保存したファイルを読み込む方法を教えて下さい。

Tags: android, android-listfragment

ArrayAdapterを継承したクラスでopenFileInputで保存したファイルを読み込む方法を教えて下さい。

お世話になっております。
　カスタムレイアウト（左からImageView、TextView）化したリストに、サイトからアプリ内で　DL保存したpng画像をセットしようとしております。
　ListFragmentで保存処理（getActivity().openFileOutput〜）を行い、別のクラス（ArrayAdapter継承）で読み出したいのですが、openFileInputが使用できず困っております。
　
　現在、FileInputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(new File("ファイル名"));が使えないか試しておりますが、動作しておりません。
　アドバイスをいただければ幸いです。

Comment: 無事、自己解決いたしました。
　解決方法を記載させていただきます。
　
　ArrayAdapterを継承したクラスのContextを利用する方法で解決出来ました。
　以下に詳細があります。
「非ActivityクラスでのopenFileOutputメソッドの利用」
　https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/android-sdk-japan/Iz9Uio5BqyA

　以上です。
　お世話をお掛けしました。